# What will happen if cast a high number of votes for about 10 days

Tags: support, flagging, votes

I am trying to get some badges so I am up voting answers that previously helped me and down voting answers that are not very good.

I have been casting about 40 votes for 3 days now and I am wondering if I will get flagged by the system (and lose my 1.2K rep)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using votes for their intended purpose: voting up good content, and voting down bad content.

Some users do get suspended for voting irregularities, which means they were targeting other users with their votes. But as long as you vote on the basis of content, this is not an issue.

Comment: I think doing voting is good for this website

Answer (score 1):

The elementary gods (particularly Freya and Loki) will smile upon you.

It's already been mentioned that there is no penalty to participating up to your daily limits (as long as it isn't looking to game the system), but as you alluded, it's also vital that we upvote more content. Our site has a very high number of new users with low rep (as opposed to users coming from other Stack Exchange sites who are familiar with SE Q&A norms). As a major consequence of their low rep (>15), users cannot even upvote on their own questions. So if many new users are asking tech support questions and even receive in-depth answers, the writer gets no rep gain (no upvotes) for their time and [our unanswered question queue suffers](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/q/214/5565). That is, unless the user somehow figures out how the accepted answer system works or if another charitable user passes by the question to sprinkle some love.