# Do not take no for an unanswer

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

We currently have [one of the lowest unanswered question rates](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#percentanswered) across all Stack Exchange sites (69%). There are a number of reasons this might be so—particularly, I look to [the design of the accepted answer toggle](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/q/211/5565) in elementary OS's low-contrast environment, and that low-rep users, who compose most of our new questions, don't have enough rep (>15) for the user privilege of upvoting the answers. BUT disregarding the reason, **we need to pull up this stat in order to [make the site out of beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82707/elementary-os)**. (The rest of our stats are okay, but we're really hurt by the [lack of upvotes](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/q/109/5565).)

Would it be useful to have a drive to do this? Any other ideas for getting this back to a reasonable state? (Stack Exchange HQ recommends at least a 90% answered rate.)

As I understand it, questions in the unanswered queue either have no answers or answers with no positive score, so it's partly a matter of validating others' work, closing outdated or vague questions that no one could answer, and requesting clarification so that these questions can get on their way.

Right now, the queue's at **940**. Can we get it to zero? (Or at least down two-thirds?)

Comment: A lot of this is questions with no answer. If you go to the unanswered queue, there aren't a lot of questions with only 0 or negative vote answers available. They are mostly actually unanswered.

Comment: For reference, me processing that queue took us from 62% to 69% in around a week, but the next 11% will be a lot harder.

Comment: I'm shooting for 1%/day (~30 questions). Finding a lot of stuff that might have appeared answerable but [now just looks like Freya bugs without workarounds](http://meta.elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/225/5565). Will be cleanup flagging liberally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent quite a few hours on this and got stuck at 73% after a week. I earlier cleared the low-hanging fruit ([answered questions that just need upvotes](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/search?q=isanswered%3A0+closed%3A0+hasaccepted%3A0+answers%3A1)) but need some relief as I can't upvote dozens of my own answers...

Which leads to the additional point that our overall participation is quite low (alluded to this in the original question). It's very despiriting to write dozens of (well-written, I think) answers only to have new users not know how to show thanks, give upvotes, or even mark their questions as resolved. Given this and [other systemic issues](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/q/232/5565), I'm finding it harder to continue investing time in this project.